# CakePHP Media Plugin Issue - undefined method MIME_Type::config()

Tags: cakephp, php

I am using the Media plugin by David Persson for CakePHP (https://github.com/davidpersson/media). I've placed the files in `app/plugins/media` and added

```
require APP . 'plugins/media/config/core.php';
```

to my app's core.php, but when I run `cake media init` I get this error:

```
Fatal Error: Call to undefined method MIME_Type::config() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wompwomp\app\plugins\media\config\core.php on line 166
```

Any idea what's happening here? Can I just make the directories manually? If so, what are the default directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to install the MIME_Type library.  The pear package for it is available [here](http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type/redirected).

**EDIT**
The proper library would be found [here](https://github.com/davidpersson/mm/tree/master/src/Mime).

Comment: Okay, how do I go about installing libraries? Is that specific to CakePHP or is it a library for PHP in general?

Comment: I looked in my php/PEAR directory and there is already a folder named MIME that has a Type.php file and a folder named Type inside of it.

Comment: Here's the [Pear package](http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type/redirected) and here's information on using [Pear on Windows](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php).

Comment: I don't know anything about the library, but make sure your local copy has the function config() in it.  If that's the case, for whatever reason, the library is not being loaded.  Does the Media plugin try to load it automatically? If not, you may need to load it.  If it does, it looks like it can't find it.

Comment: Weird, neither the local copy I had nor the one I just downloaded from Pear had a config() function in it...

Comment: Looks like he (David Persson) has a MIME_Type library too. It looks like this would need to be loaded instead of the Pear version. https://github.com/davidpersson/mm/tree/master/src/Mime

Comment: Thanks for finding that. Should I replace my system's MIME_Type library with David Persson's library or should I just point the plugin at David Persson's library.

Comment: Looking through the media/config/core.php file, it makes a simple `require 'Mime/Type.php';` call. My guess, based on what we know now, is that your library version may be getting pulled in.  Try uninstalling it if you're not using it anywhere else and see where that gets you...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the conflict between the Plugin library and Pear library:

As we all known, the order of multiple php `include_path` matters, in other words, if the PEAR  path is set before the Cake Media Plugin Built_In Mine_Type Library Path, the Mine_Type class in PEAR is found first, and the built-in one is ignored, that's the reason of the error.

To fix this, just open /app/plugins/media/config/core.php, and find the `ini_set('include_path')` directive, move the cake media plugin built-in library path to the very beginning of the INCLUDE_PATH.

That's it, enjoy!

Maybe someone can report this as a bug to the plugin author.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error on windows when i updated my php to 5.3.5 (xampp 1.7.4).

There is a conflict between Cakephp Mime Types and Pear Mime types. I rename the folder or

disable Pear Mime Type located at /php/PEAR/MIME..

That solves the problem.